# get values for a column for a historic day pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with date index. The df is grouped by date and looks like this:

```
date            ID        time_spent      
22-04-2021      ABC           60
22-04-2021      XYZ           50
22-04-2021      PQR           55
23-04-2021      XYZ           40
23-04-2021      ABC           70
23-04-2021      XYZ           95
24-04-2021      ABC           15
24-04-2021      DEF           45
24-04-2021      PQR           65
```

what I need is to create a new column tracking the time spent by each user some (eg. 3) days ago (this part needs to be flexible please). Desired result:

```
date            ID        time_spent    New_col     
22-04-2021      ABC           60          NaN
22-04-2021      XYZ           50          NaN
22-04-2021      PQR           55          NaN
23-04-2021      XYZ           40          NaN
23-04-2021      ABC           70          NaN
23-04-2021      XYZ           95          NaN
24-04-2021      ABC           15          60
24-04-2021      DEF           45          NaN
24-04-2021      PQR           65          55
```

Could someone please help me? Please bear with me if this is an elementary question, I am new to Pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex` by append `ID` to `DatetimeIndex` in [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), add `N` days to dates and join new Series by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
N = 2

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.set_index(['date','ID'])
df = (df.join(df['time_spent']
        .rename(lambda x: x + pd.Timedelta(N, 'days'), level=0)
        .rename('new'))
        .reset_index()
        )

print (df)
        date   ID  time_spent   new
0 2021-04-22  ABC          60   NaN
1 2021-04-22  PQR          55   NaN
2 2021-04-22  XYZ          50   NaN
3 2021-04-23  ABC          70   NaN
4 2021-04-23  XYZ          40   NaN
5 2021-04-23  XYZ          95   NaN
6 2021-04-24  ABC          15  60.0
7 2021-04-24  DEF          45   NaN
8 2021-04-24  PQR          65  55.0
```

Or:

```
N = 2

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df1 = (df.merge(df.assign(date = lambda x: x['date'] + pd.Timedelta(N, 'days')), 
                on=['date','ID'], 
                how='left', suffixes=('','_'))
         .rename(columns={'time_spent_':'new'}))
print (df1)
        date   ID  time_spent   new
0 2021-04-22  ABC          60   NaN
1 2021-04-22  XYZ          50   NaN
2 2021-04-22  PQR          55   NaN
3 2021-04-23  XYZ          40   NaN
4 2021-04-23  ABC          70   NaN
5 2021-04-23  XYZ          95   NaN
6 2021-04-24  ABC          15  60.0
7 2021-04-24  DEF          45   NaN
8 2021-04-24  PQR          65  55.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I get below error when I do this: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Timedelta'

Comment: Hi, I add this part and now I dont get an error, however, the new column returns the values for the same day, not for 2 days ago. I am talking about your second solution above. When I applied this to your first solution, I get the below error:IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2

Comment: Before applying your solution, I get this: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=146383, step=1). After applying your solution, I get DatetimeIndex([          '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001',
               ...,
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000146376',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000146377',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000146378',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000146379',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000146380',
'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=146383, freq=None)

Comment: I had grouped rest of the columns by date column and set date column to be index. Sorry, I thought that would make it date index

Comment: no, unfortunately still not. First solution gives an error :IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2. And second solution adds a new column with values from same day, not two days ago. How should I change the code to get correct solution please?

Comment: @user18334254 - in first solution was changed `df.set_index(['date','ID'])` and also `.reset_index()`, cn yu test if not different in your solution?

Comment: N = 2

dur.index = pd.to_datetime(dur.index)
dur['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dur['date'])

dur = df.set_index(['date','ID'])
dur = (df.join(dur['duration_total_in_mins']
        .rename(lambda x: x + pd.Timedelta(N, 'days'), level=0)
        .rename('new'))
        .reset_index()
        )

print (dur)  --> like this?

Comment: @user18334254 change `dur = (df.join(dur[` to `dur = (dur.join(dur[` and remove `dur.index = pd.to_datetime(dur.index)`

Comment: and also change `dur = df.set_index(['date','ID'])` to `dur = dur .set_index(['date','ID'])`

Comment: @user18334254 - in another words you missing `dur` and `df`, use only `dur`